# How to remove duplicate dictionary based on selected keys from a list of dictionaries in Python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, unique

I am new to Python and trying to learn it as much as possible. I am stuck with a silly problem where I want to remove certain dictionary items of a list based on selective key-value pairs. For ex, I have:

```
l = [{'A':1, 'B':2, 'C':3, 'D':4},
     {'A':5, 'B':6, 'C':7, 'D':8},
     {'A':1, 'B':9, 'C':3, 'D':10}]
```

And the output I want is removal of dictionaries based on two keys `A` and `C` values:

```
l = [{'A':1, 'B':2, 'C':3, 'D':4},
     {'A':5, 'B':6, 'C':7, 'D':8}]
```

Comment: It looks like you want to keep the first (A,C) pair seen.  Is that right?  And do you need to preserve the order?

Comment: Yes @DSM I need only those dictionaries in my final list which have unique pair of (A,C) key-values. No, order is not important.

Comment: Yes, it's clear that you only want *one* of the possibly many dictionaries with the same (A,C) pair.  But do you always need to have the *first* one, or would `{'A':1, 'B':9, 'C':3, 'D':10}` have worked equally well?

Comment: @DSM i have the same issue and interested only in the first one. how should i approach this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#set) to remember whether the items are seen.

```
>>> A, B, C, D = 'ABCD'
>>>
>>> lst = [
...     {A:1, B:2, C:3, D:4},
...     {A:5, B:6, C:7, D:8},
...     {A:1, B:9, C:3, D:10}
... ]
>>> seen = set()
>>> [x for x in lst if [(x[A], x[C]) not in seen, seen.add((x[A], x[C]))][0]]
[{'A': 1, 'C': 3, 'B': 2, 'D': 4}, {'A': 5, 'C': 7, 'B': 6, 'D': 8}]
```

Comment: Thanks @falsetru for the solution. It worked as charm! :)

Comment: What is the purpose of `A, B, C, D = 'ABCD'`? I want to use this but the keys of my dict are specific strings e.g. `slotSentence`.

Comment: ah tuple as hash - very nice.  Thanks for that